# How to share or sync a folder in remote server to Google Drive?

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, remote-server

I have a folder in my server which contains daily backup of database and uploads. When I'm uploading this folder, it shows maximum execution problem due to large size of that folder. So I want to share that folder to google drive. Is there any way to share folder?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/MRk_e2kUwlQ), it's not possible to sync Google Drive with folders outside of the original Drive folder.

Found this link - [*I need to sync files and folders outside "Google Drive" folder.*](https://superuser.com/questions/416294/can-i-sync-network-folder-with-a-google-drive) which might help.

> You can choose any folder during the Google Drive install.
>
> Firstly select "Advanced Setup" on the second page of the Getting
>   Started screen.
>
> Then click the "Change" button next to Folder Location
>
> Select any folder you want, including network shares and mapped network drives.

You can also check on this related [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/IekhOdrZE5I).